# onbehalf of email header

Tags: email

I am implementing the "onbehalfof" feature for my mail client.
However I could not find anything saying that this is a email header.

Is this a email header ?
or Is it that "on behalf of" is shown on the client when the from and sender addresses are different ?

Comment: afaik this is implemented with the 'sender' email header  (rfc822 / 4.4.2 , rfc2822 / 3.6.2)